# How to make Magisk request permission/fingerprint every time for certain apps?

Tags: security, fingerprint, magisk

I'm on Magisk v16 and I have a terminal app. I want it to require the user to use fingerprint *every time* this certain app requests root access. How do I do this?

Comment: Where do I find that module?

Comment: Also available on Play store as non Xposed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.Maxr1998.xposed.maxlock

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for- I want the normal shell to be accessable but root access to be lickedlocked down. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about fingerprints (since I don't use them), but to make Magisk prompt to grant/deny root access to an application without saving this preference, do the following:

- If you have already granted/denied root access, revoke it in Magisk Superuser settings by tapping your app and in the newly-opened list of buttons tapping "recycle bin" button.
- Next time, when the you get the prompt, be sure to change the default *Forever* option to *Once*, and only then grant/deny access.

This will grant root access for *this time*, but won't save the preference for the app. Thus, next time you'll be given the option to grant/deny again. Just don't forget to change *Forever* to *Once* each time.